# How to do sum calculations in libreoffice calc, single column

Tags: csv, libreoffice

I have a .csv file which has two columns and about 50 rows of data in them. One of the columns has some numbers in it. What should have worked is -

```
=sum<B1:B50>
```

the result should be displayed in another cell which is outside the range say B:55 but all I'm getting are hashes which tell there is an error but dunno what and there is also no explanation or error code to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=SUM(B1:B50)
```